# Where to keep Ansible Inventory file

Tags: architecture, programming-practices, version-control

I keep my Ansible based deployment module in the same repository/directory as my application code.
I use Mercurial for my VCS.

The inventories file is ephemeral as the IP's of the cloud hosts keep on getting modified.

The inventory file also defines groupings of hosts which is key information in ansible roles. So I just can't keep it separate as it is tightly coupled with the roles.

*Any addition/deletion of servers on our cloud hosts leads to change in the inventories file which gets recorded in the VCS and pollutes the repository.*

So my question is: what are the best practices regarding keeping ansible inventories in a VCS?
Should I just accept this as part of using ansible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to use example files or boilerplate files like you usually do this for `.env` files.

Add a new `inventory.example` file and set up all hosts and groups inside it. Also, add the regular `inventory` file to your ignored files so it won't be commited anymore.
If someone would like to deploy, he makes a copy of the example file and populates the file with the most current IPs and other hosts information.

This way you can specify which hosts are needed, group them and set other inventory configuration. But you do not have to commit all IP changes.
If your cloud setup does not change very often you could share the current inventory file with your coworkers via your favourite sharing method (local SMB, Dropbox, whatever..).

This is how we do it at our company and it works pretty good.

Comment: And can write a generator file that uses the template file but for every field it tries to read from the existing file and suggests that as default. Then it is easy to fill out when most fields have not changed.